# ¿Cómo unir 3 listas basándose en la propiedad id utillizando LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo 2 listas con la siguiente estructura:

```
// Lista #1:
var lista1 = [{ _idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 50},{
 _idUsuario = 2, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 60},{ _idUsuario = 3,     
_totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 70},{ _idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 0,     
_totalVenta = 10}];


// Lista #2:
var lista2 = [{ _idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 5, _totalVenta = 0},{ 
_idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 15, _totalVenta = 0}];
```

El resultado deseado es el siguiente:

```
var lista1 = [{ _idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 5, _totalVenta = 50},{ 
_idUsuario = 2, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 60},{ _idUsuario = 3, 
_totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 70},{ _idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 15, 
_totalVenta = 10}];
```

He intentado utilizar `lista1.Union(lista2)`, pero no me unifica los registros.

¿Hay alguna función de `LINQ` mas óptima para esto?, ¿o se usa usa `union` pero de una forma mas especifica?

Como nota, en la lista #1 el campo *`_totalCaptura`* siempre será 0, y el la lista #2 el campo *`_totalVenta`* siempre será 0.

Comment: No me queda del todo claro si las listas son de objetos anónimos o son referidas a una clase en particular

Comment: Creo, que tienes que mejorar tu pregunta, por que segun lo que describes no quieres unir listas, sino hacer sumatoria de las propiedades de las entidades que sean del mismo id

Comment: @Elcainas entiendo lo mismo que vos, me da la impresión que busca hacer un `group by `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que buscas con linq tendrías que combinar las listas (ya sea usando `Concat` o `AddRange`, el caso de `Union` no aplicaría, porque elimina duplicados, y no es lo que pretendemos aún) y luego usar `GroupBy`

En la práctica sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
//Concateno la segunda lista
var ListaAgrupada = lista1.Concat (lista2)
                //Agrupo por _idUsuario
                .GroupBy (x => x._idUsuario)
                //Obtengo un objeto anónimo
                .Select (x => new {
                    //Key representa el id (el campo por el que agrupamos)
                    _idUsuario = x.Key,
                        //Utilizo Sum para obtener la suma de los valores
                        _totalCaptura = x.Sum (c => c._totalCaptura),
                        _totalVenta = x.Sum (c => c._totalVenta)
                });
```

Te dejo un [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KT1eEP) del ejemplo por si te quedo una duda.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que realmente lo que deseas hacer una sumatoria de las propiedades de las entidades del mismo id, te dejo un ejemplo de `group by`, tomando como referencia una clase con tus mismas propiedades y las mismas listas de tu pregunta para llegar al resultado que esperas obtener:

```
public class UsuarioVenta
{
    public int _idUsuario { get; set; }
    public int _totalCaptura { get; set; }
    public int _totalVenta { get; set; }
}
```

Esta seria la manera de hacer el group by:

```
    // Lista #1:
    var lista1 = new List<UsuarioVenta>{
        new UsuarioVenta{ _idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 50 },
        new UsuarioVenta{ _idUsuario = 2, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 60 },
        new UsuarioVenta{ _idUsuario = 3, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 70},
        new UsuarioVenta{ _idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 0,_totalVenta = 10}
    };


    // Lista #2:
    var lista2 = new List<UsuarioVenta>{
        new UsuarioVenta { _idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 5, _totalVenta = 0},
        new UsuarioVenta{ _idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 15, _totalVenta = 0}
    };

    var listaCompleta = lista1.Union(lista2);

    var listaConsolidada = listaCompleta
        .GroupBy(x => x._idUsuario,
            (key, group) => new UsuarioVenta
            {
                _idUsuario = key,
                _totalCaptura = group.Sum(x => x._totalCaptura),
                _totalVenta = group.Sum(x => x._totalVenta)
            })
        .ToList();
```

Este seria el Output:

```
//_idUsuario = 1, _totalCaptura = 5, _totalVenta = 50
//_idUsuario = 2, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 60
//_idUsuario = 3, _totalCaptura = 0, _totalVenta = 70
//_idUsuario = 4, _totalCaptura = 15, _totalVenta = 10
```